# Qual o evento que diz que um radio button foi deselecionado dentro de um grupo de input radios?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5

Saber quando um determinado input dentro do grupo de inputs radios foi deselecionado.

```js
$('[name="teste"]').on('change', (e) => console.log(e))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>1</span>
<input type="radio" name="teste" value="1" />
<span>2</span>
<input type="radio" name="teste" value="2" />
<span>3</span>
<input type="radio" name="teste" value="3" />
<span>4</span>
<input type="radio" name="teste" value="4" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar para isso um evento que acontece antes do `change`, que é o `mousedown`:

```js
$('[name="teste"]').on('mousedown keydown', (e) => { 
  console.log("evento mousedown/keydown, valor atual: " + $('input[name="teste"]:checked').val());
});

$('[name="teste"]').on('change', (e) => { 
  console.log("evento change, novo valor: " + $('input[name="teste"]:checked').val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>1</span>
<input type="radio" name="teste" value="1" />
<span>2</span>
<input type="radio" name="teste" value="2" />
<span>3</span>
<input type="radio" name="teste" value="3" />
<span>4</span>
<input type="radio" name="teste" value="4" />
```

Comment: bem observado @AugustoVasques. Nesse caso, basta tratar tbm o evento de teclado,  `keydown` por exemplo. Atualizei o código na pergunta, obrigado por comentar

Comment: Eu já tinha deixado o +1. Obrigado pela atualização.